# How to install an custom wheel file into azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, python-wheel

I have an azure function. I want to install a python external wheel file into the function. In local, I installed using pip install . I tried placing the file in the python package and tried installing using the requirement.txt file but the function didn't get deployed.

Answer (score 0):

You can install external wheel into azure functions by following below steps:

From this  github sample of [azure python function](https://github.com/anthonyeden/Azure-Functions-Python-HTTP-Example).

You can make a HTTP request to `https://{function app name}.azurewebsites.net/api/{function name}` and test the above sample output after cloning.

- **Add the libraries that are needed:**

We can use  [pip](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/) to use to install our modules on our Azure environment.

We require two libraries,  [pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto)  and  [hdfk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hkdf).
Microsoft has a   [doc](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/06/29/install-native-python-modules-on-azure-web-apps-api-apps/)  on how to compile the module on your local windows environment. Follow those instructions to generate the pycrypto wheel that you will need in the next steps.

To tell pip what to install we need to add a requirements.txt file to the root of our project and the compiled wheels.

This is how the requirements file looks like.

```
--find-links wheelhouse
pycrypto==2.6.1
hkdf==0.0.3
```

And the updated project structure now looks a little like this

```
.
+--EDIGenerator
   +--function.json       
   +--run.py              
+--lib                     
   +--AzureHTTPHelper.py
+--wheelhouse
   +--pycrypto-2.6.1-cp27-none-win32.whl
.gitignore
host.json
README.md
requirements.txt
```

Also update the run.py to contain the code that generates an eid, you can check the implementation here:  https://github.com/myquay/Sample.Azure.Functions.Python/blob/master/EDIGenerator/run.py

**Note**: In Azure we’re going to install all these modules in a  [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).
So Python knows to import our libraries from this location make sure you have  `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'env/Lib/site-packages')))`  in any file that imports these libraries._

- **Install the libraries on our Azure Functions instance:**

We are going to run our Kudu script manually:

Open up kudu by clicking the “Go to Kudu” button under “Function app settings”.

1. Navigate to your function folder  `cd D:\home\site\wwwroot`
2. Set up your python virtual environment, the python executable is just installed in the normal place.  `D:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe env`
3. Activate your virtual environment  `"env/Scripts/activate.bat"`
4. Install from requirements.txt  `pip install -r requirements.txt`

**Note**: *If you get the error `“Unable to find vcvarsall.bat”` it means the wheel you have uploaded isn’t compatible. Make sure the wheel is compiled for the correct version of Python

Comment: Thank you but  I want to install a custom wheel file and how to install that file in the azure functions. Can you assist me here?